# What is the package to be installed in R version 2.15.2 to compute euclidean distance?

Tags: r, package, euclidean-distance

I want to find out the euclidean distance of two matrices using the `rdist()` function. It requires the *fields* package to be imported first. I am using R version 2.15.2 and unable to install this package as its giving error that `package ‘fields’ is not available (for R version 2.15.2)`. Which package should I install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really don't want to use `rdist` you could use `dist` this is in stats and so part of base

```
dist(x, method = "euclidean")
```

e.g.

```
dist(rbind( c(1,2,3), c(3,2,1) ), method = "euclidean")
# this is the distance of the two vectors
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to downlaod `R version 3.0(or higher)` and `fields package` also has dependencies - You also need to install `spam` and `maps`,

**Depends:**    R (≥ 3.0), methods, spam, maps

Comment: thank you,but is there any function to calculate euclidean distance in this version of r?

Comment: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/dist.html

Comment: Upvote if your problem is solved